# GE Profile Cooktop and element replacement

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have a [GE Profile Cooktop model PP945](https://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-specs/PP945BMBB). The right rear heating element is out. The right rear element is the small 1200W unit. I disassembled the unit and found the heating coil burned out (discolorization around the 10:00 position).

[image]

The unit has been in service for about 7 years. This is the first problem. The right rear element is used less frequently and has the fewest duty cycles. The other elements are used more frequently.

I don't know the cause of the failure. I'm not sure if I should replace the element alone, or the element and the sensor. Or maybe something else. (I believe the sensor is the bar running horizontally in the image).

What is the recommended course of action for this repair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My course of action would be to replace the burner. It's only $59.28 at partselect.com. You've already done the hard part, which it removing the bad burner. Reassembling it will be faster.

Comment: Ack, thanks. Man, GE does a poor job of identifying their parts. It took me half an hour to remove and tear down the unit, and about two hours to identify the correct part. The numbers stamped on the unit are not the catalogue part numbers.

Comment: I had a Maytag with the same problem. Small burner out after 3 years. good luck.